# Jquery Draggable and Resizable on Same element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a `<div class="outerDiv"></div>` and i am dynamically adding another `div` over it which i want to make draggable as well as resizable within this `outerDiv`

`.isStore` is css class of the div which i want to make draggable and Resizable.

```
$(".outerDiv .isStore").draggable({ containment: ".outerDiv" }).resizable({ containment: ".outerDiv" });
```

thje problem is i am not able to resize the `div` to full width of `OuterDiv`

[image]

In above snap The `div` with grid is `outerDiv` and red colour shows the `div` which is draggable and resizable but this is the maximum size i can resize. i want it to resize all over the `outerDiv`.

the css i am using is

```
.outerDiv
 {
   width: 202px;
   overflow:auto;
   overflow: auto;
   display:inline-block;
 }

.isStore
 {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   background-color: #fff7f8;
   border: 1px SOLID;
   float: left;
   position:absolute;
 }
```

is there something i am missing?

Comment: Try to put sample code in something like jsfiddle first or at least provide sscce.

Comment: Please go to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and create a test case to reproduce this, then Save it and link to it in your answer. You may want to remove some of the unnecessary styles such as `position:absolute` and `float:left` since the jQuery UI takes care of this stuff for you when you make the element `draggable`. Also, there is no height defined on your container `outerDiv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use your browser's developer tools to find out whether there are some constraints defined (like CSS `max-height` / `max-width` maybe?). If you have Chrome, you can right click the element and view the Styles/Computed tab to see what it may be picking up. When solving problems like this it helps to simplify the example and gradually add complexity.

This works OK with this simple example (with no CSS `max` constraints):

```js
$(".outerDiv .isStore").draggable({ containment: ".outerDiv" }).resizable({ containment: ".outerDiv" });
```

```css
.isStore
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  }
.outerDiv
{
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='outerDiv'><div class='isStore'></div></div>
```

This simulates your problem by adding CSS `max-height` and `max-width` constraints.

```js
$(".outerDiv .isStore").draggable({ containment: ".outerDiv" }).resizable({ containment: ".outerDiv" });
```

```css
.isStore
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  }
.outerDiv
{
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class='outerDiv'><div class='isStore'></div></div>
```

You can try setting these styles to `auto` like this:

```
.isStore
{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}
```

Comment: i was using Jquery-ui.js which was corrupted ! i replaced it with new one and that worked fine!

Comment: Corruption is worse than prostitution.